# Compiling .as file in Flex SDK that extends a base class

Tags: class, actionscript, compiler-construction, radix

I am simply trying to compile a .as file that extends another .as file like this:

public class BigSquare extends Square{
...
}

I go to the command line and type:

mxmlc BigSquare.as

The error I get is "The definition of base class Square was not found."

Where do I need to place the base class Square.as in order for BigSquare.as to compile?

Answer (score 0):

You should add to the command line parameters the "-source-path" with the path to the other files you use at compile time (i.e. Square.as). More information here: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_13.html . You call should look like this

```
mxmlxc -source-path "path/to/Square.as" BigSquare.as
```

Hope it helps.